# DDS BC7 Thumbnails on Windows 10

Tags: texture, directx

Is it possible to enable accurate thumbnail previews for DDS files that use the newer DX10 headers (DirectX 10 headers)? It seems there is very limited information about this.

I did find a couple posts on random sites that suggest using "Sage Thumbs" with any app that supports newer DDS formats, but this did not work for me. I tried setting (as the default primary app for DDS) the newest Photoshop with the NVidia exporter plugin, as well as the latest Paint.net. Sage Thumbs does enable thumbnails for newer DDS files, but all of the thumbnail images are garbled, with pixel bleeding, and some with pure pixel noise.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully? Having these previews would make working with the compressed BC6 and BC7 formats far easier.

Comment: Have you tried setting the stand alone version of the Nvidia exporter: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-exporter as the default program to open DDS files? (not photoshop with plugin)

Comment: I didn't, but tried just now. Unfortunately, I seem to get the same results when using Sage Thumbs, regardless of which app is set as the default/primary. Exactly the same defects. I'm wondering if there is a  setting somewhere. Thank you for the suggestion.